# в laravel дублируются css стили

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

Дублируются в laravel CSS стили, а файл подключен 1шт, использую OpenServer
дублируются по пути:

- /style/main.css
- /public/style/main.css
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('public/style/main.css')}}">
</head>
```

```
# корень сайта .htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# папка public .htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Не совсем понял что значит "дублируются по пути", вот тут `{{asset('public/style/main.css')}}"` должно быть без `public`.

Comment: @Simon добавил картинку как дублируются, изменил как Вы сказали. теперь дублируются так:  1путь) САЙТ/style/main.css     2путь) САЙТ/style/main.css      т.е они одинаковые и идет дублирование стилей.